# Which method is used to terminate the execution of Java program in between?

Tags: java

We used functions like exit() in C++ to abnormally terminate the execution of program, which function can we use in Java.
For ex :- In following program I want to terminate the execution as soon the value of i is printed for 1st time.

```
//following is the program :  
class Lcm {
        public static void main( String args[] ) {

            int a = Integer.parseInt( args[0] );
            int b = Integer.parseInt( args[1] );

            for ( int i=1 ; i<=a*b ; i++ ) {
                if ( i%a==0 && i%b==0 ) {
                    System.out.println( "lcm is: " + i );
                    /* i want to terminate the program
                     * when the value of i is printed
                     * for very 1st time
                     */
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your question correcltly.

Answer (score 11):

`System.exit(0)` or `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0)`

Comment: They are same. `System.exit(0)` is implemnted as `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0)`

Comment: @Eng. yes it is. System.exit() would call Runtime.getRuntime().exit()

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `break` to get out of the loop and let the function end naturally, or a plain `return` to exit the function altogether.

Perhaps it is finally time to learn to control your flow without `goto` statements and their equivalents (`exit`, `longjmp`, `try..catch` used for flow control etc).

Answer (score 2):

This is a good way to end the application in Java:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Example:

```
if (num1 == num2) {
  System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [System.exit(int status)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) method has this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Please explore System.exit(). http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html
Exit of the control flow from main thread also implies the completion of a program and is normally used.

Answer (score 0):

In `C`, `C++` and `Java` the program terminates when the `main/Main` function/method returns. The difference is that in in`Java` the return type `Main` is `void`. On normal termination it always returns **success**.

To indicate an abnormal termination and return a non-zero exit code, use `System.exit`.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case you could simply escape the loop by using `break`, which would look like the following:

```
for ( int i = 1 ; i <= a*b ; i++ ) {
    if ( i%a == 0 && i%b == 0 ) {
        System.out.println( "lcm is: " + i );
        break;
    }
}
```

Because there's no code following, but you can also, as other mentioned before, use the `System.exit(0)` command for actually terminating your program.

Another possible way is to change your code a bit and put the `if-statement` directly in our loop-termination. This way could look like this:

```
int i = 0;
while (++i < a*b && !(i % a == 0 && i % b == 0));
System.out.println(j);
```

which is a bit more difficult to read, but you don't need a additional command to end your program. The semicolon behind the ´while-condition´ simply says that while the loop is running, nothing should be done. In that case your loop simply counts up your variable. For a better readability you could also put the counting of ´i´ in the body of the loop.