# How to stop a long function execution after refreshing page in java?

Tags: java, function, class

i am calling a java function which send a soap request and from that request i am getting 50000 data count and page becomes heavy. When i try to reload or going back to previous page or some other tab in between the function execution then i am able to move successfully but in background the java function executing.

I want to stop the execution of that function as soon as i move to different page or tab. How can i do that in java?

Already gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600812/which-method-is-used-to-terminate-the-execution-of-java-program-in-between) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041770/stop-executing-further-code-in-java) posts.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you considered something like pagination, or lazy loading..?

Comment: Lazy loading is more popular nowadays. Certain sites (e.g. http://www.computerra.ru/lenta/) implement lazy loading quite nicely

Comment: @TJ i can't use pagination as i want that data to create charts and also i think about lazy loading but i can't use it as i want to display chart as soon as  i get full data. Both options are invalid for my case.

Comment: @TarunSharma Is real time relevant? if not consider caching those charts.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to arrange that the function periodically checks to see if it should stop.  You could do this with an ad-hoc flag (e.g. a `volatile boolean` field), or you could use the thread "interrupt" mechanism..